# What's up with the number next to the review button?

Tags: support, bug

Next to the "review" button at the top banner there is a number in an orange square that appears periodically. In the past it was a number indicating that there are suggested edits waiting to be reviewed, and pressing on it would take me to the suggested edit review.

Now it takes me to the general edit page, but more strangely is that it shows a number even though all the review ques are empty, and keeps it even after a refresh of the page.

What does the number mean?

[image]

On Stack Overflow, the number still works the same, shows how many suggested edits are waiting to be reviewed, and it takes me straight to the suggested edits review cue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the number of reviews available to *anyone*. As of a couple weeks ago, [anyone who has earned the moderator tools privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much/230802#230802) is shown the total count of pending reviews in all queues rather than just the number of edits they can review.

You might be confused as you don't see any open reviews, the big issue is that the count is not personalized and ignores that you might have already reviewed all of the available stuff. It is also cached for several minutes between updates, although it will drop to reflect tasks completed during this time.

While this does reduce the usefulness of the number as a simple indicator of what is new, it does serve as an indication of when the site is in trouble: if *you've* reviewed all available items and the tasks remain in review for an extended period of time, then there's a problem: your reviews are effectively wasted until someone else (other users or moderators) go through and review the pending tasks as well.

There are [some discussions on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar) on whether this could be made less annoying.

Comment: The cashed issue is (was) resolved by refreshing (at least at SO and in the past). After reviewing all available posts, the number would stay the same, once the browser paged is refreshed, the number would get updated, at the moment it doesn't happen, but still works on SO. I think it started once I went over the 10K rep, so maybe it's some how related to this.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed It doesn't take into account whether you reviewed something already or not, so it will be always wrong when some reviews are still open that you reviewed yourself.

Comment: then why does it take me to the general review page and not the suggested reviews page when I press on it. Even when there are suggested edits to review?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed I think it is supposed to do that, this indicator is different from the old suggested edit counter.

Comment: Then this behavior is different from other sites, both SO and Arqade (the only other sites where I have review privileges) the counter shows how many suggested edits reviews are available and takes you straight to the suggested edits review page. I think that we should align with the rest of the SE network.

Comment: See my edit, @IlyaMelamed - this is the same everywhere, but your status is different here than it is elsewhere.